# Control key not working in Kitty or Alacritty but it works in iterm2

Tags: iterm, zsh

I'm using zsh with iterm2 but I wanted to switch to another emulator like kitty or alacritty and I have a problem which I cannot figure out:

In iterm2 Control based combinations work but in kitty or alacritty they do not. All have the same output for `$TERM` (`xterm-256color`) but output of `cat -v` is different:

In iterm2 I get:

```sh
> cat -v
^R
```

But both in kitty and alacritty:

```sh
> cat -v
r
```

The same goes for other Control- shortcuts like C-c, C-d etc.

What could be causing this? I'm using Karabiner-Elements but nothing fancy there. Outside of those 2 apps, Control seems to be working fine. (This is on Big Sur 11.2.1)